# Show the semantic equivalence of the Distributive Law

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have been stuck for a while trying to solve this, but it feels incomplete.

We first consider the distributivity and therefore start by proving that

$$a ∨ (b ∧ c) ╞ (a∨b)∧(a∨c)$$

Supose that for a value we have

$$a ∨ (b ∧ c) = True$$

Then

$$a = True$$ or $$(b∧c) = True $$

What then?

Here I would make the jump to the right side of the equation, but I am unsure on how to concretely do it.

Also I am only proving this for one side of the equation, I will then have to do the oposite side and a similar proof for the other Distributive Law so a concrete answer would be nice.

Comment: Use the definition. The RHS is a conjuncition. What needs to happen for a conjunction to be true? Can you prove, in each case, that those things that need to happen, do happen indeed?

Comment: I am completely clueless as to what you mean, What even is RHS?

Comment: It's short for right-hand side (right-hand side of $\models$, i.e. $(a\lor b)\land (a\lor c)$). Is the term '[valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(logic))' unfamiliar to you?

Comment: Many of these terms are unfamiliar to me, my country is not English speaking. I've figured out by conjunction you mean the And symbol, I cannot prove this with a truth table, as it would defeat the purpose.

Comment: But truth tables are part of the definition of $\models$. How are you defining the symbol $\models$?

Comment: It's been proven by the teacher, valuation, tautology, conjunction and disjunction, the teacher then used these to prove the first DeMorgan Law, which is (roughly) the method Iam trying to follow to prove the Distributive Laws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have disjoined the antecedent (the first statement) into two cases.   So use a **proof by cases** to show that *both* entail the desired consequent (the second statement).

$$\begin{align}a\vee(b\wedge c) & \vDash a, b\wedge c \\[2ex] a & \vDash a\vee b \\ a & \vDash a\vee c \\\hline a & \vDash (a\vee b)\wedge(a\vee c)\\[2ex]\vdots\\[2ex]
a & \vDash (a\vee b)\wedge (a\vee c) \\ b\wedge c & \vDash (a\vee b)\wedge (a\vee c) \\\hline a\vee(b\wedge c) & \vDash (a\vee b)\wedge (a\vee c) \end{align}$$

> For the first case, assume $a$ is true.   Then either $a$ or $b$ are true.   Also, either $a$ or $c$ are true.   So then both either $a$ or $b$ and either $a$ or $c$ hold true.   Hence the first case entails the desired result.
>
> For the second case, assume both $b$ and $c$ are true.   Then ...
>
> As both the first and second case entail the desired consequent, then the original antecedent entails the desired consequent.   And we are done.